# @PersistenceContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, javabeans, managed-bean

I was running a code in which there's a dependency `@PersistenceContext` and a field `private EntityManager em`; both of which cannot be resolved to a type, what is the meaning of this error and how can I fix it?
The code is here:

```
package org.jboss.tools.examples.util;    

import java.util.logging.Logger;     
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;     
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;     
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;     
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;     

/**    
 * This class uses CDI to alias Java EE resources, such as the persistence context, to     
CDI beans    
 *     
 * <p>    
 * Example injection on a managed bean field:    
 * </p>    
 *     
 * <pre>    
 * &#064;Inject    
 * private EntityManager em;    
 * </pre>    
 */    
public class Resources {    
   // use @SuppressWarnings to tell IDE to ignore warnings about field not being         referenced directly    
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")    
   @Produces    
   @PersistenceContext    
   private EntityManager em;    

   @Produces    
   public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {    
      return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());    
   }    

   @Produces    
   @RequestScoped    
   public FacesContext produceFacesContext() {    
      return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing import statement for PersistenceContext annotation and EntityManager

```
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
```

Comment: thanks Anshu, now i'm getting:
    The import javax.persistence cannot be resolved
    The import javax.persistence cannot be resolved

Comment: Please make sure that you have the required libraries in your classpath

Comment: that resolved now i have "NotEmpty cannot be resolved to a type" `@NotEmpty` and "Email cannot be resolved to a type" `@Email` :)

Comment: If you are using an IDE, cannot you just do an organize imports?